# PHP - mail() function doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm working on one small "demo request" form. That form should be send request for demo on my email address.
Process:
1) User want demo, just need to fill this form and press Submit.
2) I'll get email with details and after I can be in touch with client using details from email (username, email)

I'm using PHP mail() function for that but doesn't want to send me message on email.
I tried from my localhost and also from mail hosting server. Doesn't work in both case.

HTML FORM:

```
<form id="RD-form" method="post" action="php/request-demo.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Your name"><br><br>
    <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your email address"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$sendto = "test@gmail.com";
$username = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

echo "Hello , my name is ".$username.". I want to try demo version. Please contact me on ".$email."";

$message = "Hello!\n My name is ".$username.". I want to try demo version. \nPlease contact me on ".$email."";
mail($sendto, $username, $message);
```

As you can see, echo function works good, just mail() makes a problem.

Comment: try setting headers like here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have tested the code and it worked for me although there are things that can be improved like missing header and assuming the test@gmail.com is merely a generic example.

Comment: I have added my personal (denislapidenis@gmail.com) email address but didn't worked.

Comment: I suggest you to combine it on a single php file and troubleshoot from there. 1) use mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 2) add name="submit" to your submit input 3) local server won't work

Comment: I just replaced header and also name="submit". I'll try to upload on my server

Comment: Hey mate, this works now! Thank a lot! :)